# Want to create a download button that fades to another image on hover and then to a third image on click

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events, fadein, fadeout

Please forgive me if my question is too simple. I am VERY new at this!

I'm trying to create a button for downloading a file on my site.

I want the button to change when a user hovers over it and then when they click it I want it to change to a 3rd image and start downloading the file.

Here's what I have so far (I have the 2 images fading on hover with this)...

```
<div id="cf">
<img class="download" src="/Images/downloading.png" alt="download3" />
  <img class="bottom" src="/Images/PDownloadAllFiles2.png" alt="download2" />
  <img class="top" src="http:///Images/PDownloadAllFiles1.png" alt="download1" />
</div>

<head>
<style type="text/css">

#cf {
  position:relative;
  height:281px;
  width:450px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#cf img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}

#cf img.download:transparent {
opacity:0;
}
#cf_onclick {
cursor:pointer;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cf_onclick").click(function() {
  $("#cf2 img.download").toggleClass("transparent");
});
});
</script>

</head>
```

This code only fades image 1 into image 2 when hovering over it.

what do I need to add in order for this button to change on click to the 3rd image and start downloading the file?

Answer (score 0):

just add the javascript code to change the source of the image to the third image

```
function onButtonClick(){
  document.getElementById('yourElementId').src = 'third.png';
}
```

Comment: Hmmm.. So is it not changing the source or what??? can you give the snippet of the code how and where you added?

Comment: Here is where I added it...

`<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cf_onclick").click(function() {
  $("#cf2 img.download").toggleClass("transparent");
});
function onClick(){
  document.getElementById('Perform At Your Best').src = '/Files/Perform At Your Best.zip';
}
});
});
</script>`

Comment: What is "Perform At Your Best"? Is it an id of your tag or what? And what is "Perform At Your Best.zip" doing in your code? The things are pretty messed up...I really want to help...Should I give you a simple example without jQuery, how you can do the desired task?

Comment: Yes please... and thank you for taking pity on me! :-)

Perform At Your Best is the id of my tag and "Perform At Your Best.zip" is the file I want to have the user download when the pic is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

@George Watson I have no idea why you have given .zip file as the source of your tag..anyways lets move

Below I have the code which will work for the background colors. Just see the output of the code and if this is the pattern which you desired then you just have to provide an image in the background of the three div's and you are done.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>sumitb.mdi</title>
<style>
    #container{
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        height:100px;
        width: 300px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
    .customButton{
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #myButton1{
        background-color: red;  
    }
    #myButton2{
        background-color: blue; 
        opacity:0; 
        -webkit-transition:opacity 1s linear;
    }
    #myButton2:hover{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    #myButton3{
        visibility: hidden;
        background-color: silver;
    }


</style>

<script>
function onContainerClick(){
    document.getElementById('myButton3').style.visibility='visible';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='container' onclick='onContainerClick();'>
    <div id='myButton1' class='customButton'></div>
    <div id='myButton2' class='customButton'></div>
    <div id='myButton3' class='customButton'></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

To provide the background image in the div do this:

```
#myButton1{
....
background-image:url('one.png');
...
}
```

Similarly do for the other two divs 
That was all about the client side; after that you have to code the server side for file downloading stuff.

Comment: This works AWESOME! Thanks!
I am having trouble getting the button now to actually download the file. In my older button I used this code to download the file...
`<a href="http://filelocationurl.com/Files/Perform At Your Best.zip" download="Perform At Your Best.zip" title="Perform At Your Best">
<img alt="Perform At Your Best" src="http://filelocationurl.com/Images/myButton1" name="rollover_one" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()" style="border: none;"/></a>`
I just put this at the bottom -after the script. That doesn't work now so where do I put this for the button to work?

Comment: Suppose that button two is your download button then in my above given code do these changes where i mentioned myButton2 in html: `<a href='http://filelocationurl1.com/Files/Perform At Your Best.zip' download='Perform At Your Best' title='Perform At Your Best'><div id='myButton2' class='customButton'></div></a>`

Comment: Hmmm... ya, that's not workin' either... it's like my html code doesn't even exist! I'm going to keep playing with it. I'll let you know tomorrow if I can get it working...

Comment: I added the href to the myButton2 div and it worked for downloading only now when it's clicked it doesn't turn into myButton3! Here's what I did... `<div id='container' onclick='onContainerClick();'>
    <div id='myButton1' class='customButton'></div>
    <div id='myButton2' class='customButton'><a href='http://filelocationurl.com/Files/Perform At Your Best.zip' download='Perform At Your Best' title='Perform At Your Best'></a></div>
    <div id='myButton3' class='customButton'></div>`